# Android RecyclerView invalid item height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with android recyclerview.
So I have an comment item, that can have some kind of a "read more" button.
I add several comment items into view. Some of them have read modre feature, some of them no.
The problem is, when i expand one of item and make several scrolls, other element
could have height of expanded item, even if this element may not be expandable.

///////Code of Single Item

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_comment_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_margin_small">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/commentAuthorPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/news_details_item_comment_photo_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_item_comment_photo_size"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin_small" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_item_comment_photo_size"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/commentDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_10"
                    attr:custom_font="@string/font_open_sans_regular"
                    tools:text="10 Nov 12:45" />

                <FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/commentAuthorName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/comment_author_name_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14"
                    attr:custom_font="@string/font_open_sans_bold"
                    tools:text="Jane Doe" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                expandableTextView:animDuration="200"
                expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="3">

                <FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12"
                    attr:custom_font="@string/font_open_sans_regular"
                    tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_medium" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="4dp" />
            </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_item_comment_bot_view_h"
        android:background="@color/news_details_item_comment_bot_view_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_margin_small"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_margin_small">

        <CounterView
            android:id="@+id/commentLikesCount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            attr:counter_image="@drawable/ic_v_like_red"
            attr:counter_text_color="@color/comment_counter_text_color" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/commentDeleteBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_trash_btn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/commentLikeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_like_comment_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

One of the elements is https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView.
So if item can expand (text view contains more than 3 lines), if I scroll up of down, some other element will have each height as previosly expanded item.

Comment: Are u set `hasFixedSize` to `false `?

Comment: yep. I think that the reason is in LinearLayoutManager. Think it's saving last params of view that was binded. and when it's bind expanded view, it apply same params to another items. But I dont't know how to fix it

Comment: I reread your topic. Maybe, u're right. Then you can write custom layout manager to fix it

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't remember method now but it will contain 'measure' or 'size' words. Just find it in a source code of library or Android SDK, or docs references

Comment: Just I understood at begin that your items have same height after app launching

Comment: @Шах yep at the start, all of views have same height

Comment: Then problem is not the layout manager. You need to set `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)`

Comment: If it didn't help you then post your code and item xml

Comment: No, it's not working. I will attach some code

Comment: Sorry, but I need all code (adapter and setup of your `RecyclerView`: where you set adapter, layoutmanager and etc). And if you can post a screenshot too where you have problem with height. Even if I can't help you will get help from others more quickly

Answer (score 0):

This is a reusability error. Check on Onbindviewholder should also be closed if the item is not expand. For example:

```
 if(item.isExpanded){
 textView.expand()
 }
 else{
 textView.collapse()
}
```